# How to transfer ownership of apps on windows marketplace?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8

I need to transfer ownership of my apps to somebody else on windows marketplace.

The procedure is easy on Apple's App Store and Google's Play Store, but could not find a solution on windows marketplace.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is possible to transfer ownership of apps in the Windows Marketplace from one account to another.

## Contact support

1. Visit the [Dev Center support page](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/community/support) and select any of problem types listed.
2. Change **Problem type** to "Store registration and your account" and **Category** to "Other"
3. Select **Start Email** and fill in all the details of the app you want to transfer

## **Details you'll need**

Current Account

- Microsoft Account
- Developer Guid
- App Name
- App Guid

Transferring to Account

- Microsoft Account
- Developer Guid

Source: [Spaso Lazarevic Blog](https://spasol.wordpress.com/2013/11/24/windows-phone-application-migration-from-one-account-to-another/)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Neil's answer, (This is too long for a comment) :

Trying to do it these days, there are a few constraints that are worth noting (copy paste the support answer) :

- Apps must be published to the store
- There cannot be any “in progress” submissions or “package flights” for the apps
- Apps may not contain in-app purchases
- Requests must be made from the source account
- All Ad campaigns paid and/or house must be paused
- Apps must have reserved names
- App may not use MPNS
- Apps may not use WNS for push notifications

Additional requirements: If the source account (i.e. owns the apps) is a business account then written authorization is required authorizing Microsoft to transfer the apps. This should be in the form of a notarized letter listing the following details:

- Name of the source account/company
- Source account’s Microsoft Account (email address)
- Name of the app(s) and the Big ID (app id) to be transferred
- Target account’s publisher name and Microsoft Account
- Letter must be notarized

Before any paid apps can be migrated the tax profile and payout account must first be validated on the new account (Target account) prior to the migration. In addition, if the target account is also a company account, the ID Validation must be completed.

Some considerations:

- Ratings and reviews will migrate to the new account
- Reporting data stays on the original account.
- The new account will only begin accruing earnings for any sales after the app migration to the new account is complete.
- You must export all download reporting payout data before the migration. Once the migration is complete this information will no longer be available for export on either account.
- Apps will continue to display the old publisher name in the marketplace until a new update has been published from the new account.?